# Create a SOAP-producer without spring Boot but Spring integration

Tags: java, spring, soap

I have a WSDL-file, which describes properties of a SOAP-requests (XSD-parts and also service-parts). Using Maven, I was able to generate model classes.
Now I want to use given classes to provide some SOAP-services.
Most of tutorials using Spring Boot, but I don't want. They also use a given wsdl-file and xsd-file, which I don't have.

All I want, is to have a easy to code SOAP endpoint, which uses Spring integration, where I can use stuff link @Inject. Do you have an idea?